# How do I make a Range reverse on condition?

Tags: rust, range, conditional-statements

I have a range, that I want to reverse if a condition is satisfied. Since `for i in 0..9` will iterate the same way as `for i in 9..0` simply swapping out the numbers will not work. Also `(0..9).stepy_by(-1)` is not an option as `.step_by()` only accepts a `usize`. Therefore I tried so implement something like the following:

```rust
fn create_range(rev: bool) -> Range<usize> {
    if rev {
        0..9
    } else {
        (0..9).rev()
    }
}
```

Which unfortunately also des not work since `0..9` returns a `Range<usize>` but `(0..9).rev()` returns a `Rev<Range<usize>>` so the types do not match.

I ended up putting everything that I call within the loop in a function but I am not really satisfied with that.

```rust
if rev {
    for i in (0..9).rev() {
        do_stuff(i);
    }
} else {
    for i in 0..9 {
        do_stuff(i);
    }
}
```

The question is: Would it be simply possible to reverse a range if a condition is satisfied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`itertools` has the type `Either` that can be used to return either of two compatible iterators:

```rust
use itertools; // 0.8.2

fn create_range(
    rev: bool,
) -> itertools::Either<impl Iterator<Item = usize>, impl Iterator<Item = usize>> {
    if !rev {
        itertools::Either::Left(0..9)
    } else {
        itertools::Either::Right((0..9).rev())
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Not reversed:");
    for a in create_range(false) {
        println!("{}", a);
    }

    println!("Reversed:");
    for a in create_range(true) {
        println!("{}", a);
    }
}
```

[(Permalink to the playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b79dddc0db1fc5788d0780875a2f53f8)

Comment: I don't know who down voted this answer. For me this answer the question.

Comment: This is a good answer to the question. Unfortunately when simplifying it I left out, that I return a tuple of ranges which I can't get to work with generics. See the [Playgroud](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e32267fa7f76c7af4ee5b5501c9c09a0). Is there an error or is a tuple not working with generics?

Comment: @sezi80 from the usage, it looks like you want to [return a tuple of `Either`s, rather than an `Either` of tuples](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=473c56376e353279f720f359fef5e7a5).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without `itertools`:

```rust
fn create_range(rev: bool) -> impl Iterator<Item = usize> {
    let (mut start, step) = if rev {
        (9usize, usize::max_value())
    } else {
        (usize::max_value(), 1)
    };

    std::iter::repeat_with(move || {
        start = start.wrapping_add(step);
        start
    })
    .take(9)
}

fn main() {
    println!("Not reversed:");
    for a in create_range(false) {
        println!("{}", a);
    }

    println!("Reversed:");
    for a in create_range(true) {
        println!("{}", a);
    }
}
```

[(Permalink to the playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a0e662451dbf2f960c3f166517d2ca48)

This is a bit more complicated and won't generalize as easily to things that are not ranges. It might be a tiny bit faster as well. The dance with `usize::max_value()` and `wrapping_add` is necessary to avoid overflow checks, but is perfectly defined.

Comment: You can probably edit your above answer, no need for double posting.

Comment: @DanielFath Those are two different solutions. Posting two different answers to the same question is fine on SO.

Comment: I don't think these are really multiple independent answers https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384665/how-to-handle-a-user-that-leaves-multiple-answers-per-question

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about allocation and performance isn't a huge concern, you can do something like:

```rust
let vals = if start < end {
    (start..end).collect::<Vec<_>>()
} else {
    (end..start).rev().collect::<Vec<_>>()
};
for i in vals {
    ...
}
```

Obviously this isn't ideal since you're allocating all those numbers, but it's a quick/dirty solution that might work in some cases.